# How to know the width and height of a moving figure everytime I click on it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I have a doubt about a moving figure that starts from the left side of the screen and finishes on the upper right area of the screen.

Let's see. I'm a newbie on this. I'm doing this on Canvas and JS, also with jQuery. I have a moving figure that everytime I click on it (or the Canvas) changes its color.

But my problem is on the following thing: When I click on the moving object, I want that object to tell me its width and height. But the one who is telling me its width and height is the canvas, not the moving figure.

How can I improve that? What is the thing that i'm doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Moving Figure</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400" style="border:1px solid #000000"></canvas>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>

    <script>

    var color = ['green', 'red', 'blue', 'purple', 'yellow'];
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var posicion = 0;    
    var tamano = 0;

    setInterval(function () {

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 400, 400);
    ctx.fillRect(posicion, 0, tamano, 400-tamano);

    posicion++;
    tamano++;

    if (posicion > 400){
        posicion = 0;
        tamano = 0;
        ctx.fillStyle = color[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)]; 
        }
    }, 30);


    $("#canvas").click(function(){
        ctx.fillStyle = color[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)];

    $("p").text( "The Width of the figure is " + event.pageX + " and the Height is " + event.pageY);
    });

  </script>
   <p id="texto"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Its the click event for the `canvas`, so  `event.pageX` and `event.pageY` is the event for the canvas itself. It knows nothing about the figure. You will need to look at the coordinates that the mouse was on a click, depend if it's clicking on the figure based on it's position. But you should be keeping the `width` and `height` of the figure instead, or should be able to compute it based on your variables `posicion` and `tamano`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because for the click event for the `canvas`, The items `event.pageX` and `event.pageY` will be with respect to the canvas. Although you can figure out the width and height of your figure because you are stating it in your statement here:

```
ctx.fillRect(posicion, 0, tamano, 400-tamano);
```

The events parameters are `fillRect(x, y, width, height)`. So the width will be `tamano` and the height is `400-tamano`:

```
$("p").text( "The Width of the figure is " + tamano+ " and the Height is " + (400-tamano));
```

This will happen on simply clicking on the canvas, if you wish it to update only when you click on the figure, you can do a collision detection by getting the `x,y,width,height` of the value compared to the `mouseX,mouseY` of the mouse:

```
$("#canvas").click(function(e){
    var cRect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    var mouseX = e.clientX - cRect.left;
    var mouseY = e.clientY - cRect.top;        

    var figureX = posicion;
    var figureY = 0;
    var figureW_off = posicion + tamano;
    var figureH_off = 400-tamano;      
    ctx.fillStyle = color[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)];

    if(mouseX >= figureX && mouseX <= figureW_off &&
       mouseY >= figureY && mouseY <= figureH_off)
    {
        $("p").text( "The Width of the figure is " + tamano+ " and the Height is " + (400-tamano));
    }
});
```

[**Fiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/xt1hsym1/)

Answer (score 1):

You must use the variable `tamano` to get the size of that element.

Be aware, that your element goes 'outside' of the canvas, so the width might seem a little weird.

Working snippet:

```js
var color = ['green', 'red', 'blue', 'purple', 'yellow'];
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var posicion = 0;
var tamano = 0;

setInterval(function () {

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 400, 400);
    ctx.fillRect(posicion, 0, tamano, 400 - tamano);

    posicion++;
    tamano++;

    if (posicion > 400) {
        posicion = 0;
        tamano = 0;
        ctx.fillStyle = color[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)];
    }
}, 30);


$("#canvas").click(function () {
    ctx.fillStyle = color[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)];

    $("p").text("The Width of the figure is " + tamano + " and the Height is " +  (400 - tamano));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400" style="border:1px solid #000000"></canvas>
<p id="texto"></p>
```